# Import error from "Django Tutorial: a Todo List App"

Tags: django

I am confused on this part of the [Django tutorial](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html#customizing-model-template). It says something like copying the whole `admin` templates to `dbe/templates`, but what is the full path should be and what folders am I suppose to be creating?

I am running Mac OS X and my todo app is located at `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/todo/` and my full Django path is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packges/django/`.

I also placed my templates at `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/myDjango/templates`. Inside this folder I have `admin/base_site.html` and `polls/detail.html`, `polls/index.html`, and `polls/results.html`. The poll app was created from the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01). My copy of the poll app works fine.

The error I get when I run the server with `python manage.py runserver` and I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` is

```
ImportError at /admin/

No module named dbe.todo.models

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named dbe.todo.models

Exception Location:     /Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/todo/admin.py in <module>, line 1
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:    

['/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']

Server time:    Fri, 24 Feb 2012 05:09:28 -0600
```

Comment: "It says something like copying the whole admin templates to dbe/templates" Where does it say so ? Post all your code, the procedure to reproduce the error, and the full traceback. TYIA :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry I forgot to post the error before I hit "Post Question". The exact instructions are in the first link I posted above.

Comment: Please define what is 'dbe' ?

Comment: Also, help me to help you :) i asked: "It says something like copying the whole admin templates to dbe/templates" Where does it say so ? and 'Post all your code, the procedure to reproduce the error' (particularely settings). Come on don't be shy :D

Comment: Lol that's what I'm trying to figure out. In the `mysite/todo/admin.py`, the guy imports `from dbe.todo.models import *` and that's where the problem resides. I hope that helps.

Comment: Humn, i thought you were linking **the official polls app tutorial**. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/.

Comment: No, this link: http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html#customizing-model-template

I guess I'm suppose to create a folder called `dbe`, but I don't know what to put in it and where to place the folder... If you look at the bottom of the last page. It gives you the entire source code in a tarball.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, you should follow the official tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

The tutorial you're following looks pretty awful (sorry :/)

I suspect that dbe is the project name of this guy. When he shows:

```
cp -r django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/ dbe/templates/
```

It seems that he has django and the project at the same level. So his dbe == your mysite.

Anyhow, there is no need to prefix app modules with the project module name, this is ridiculous - hard coding the project name in the apps. This totally defeats the purpose of reusable apps. Run this:

```
find /path/to/your/project -type f | xargs sed -i -e s/dbe.//g
```

This command will remove 'dbe.' from everywhere in your code. This tutorial code is so horrible I wonder why you even bother following it ...

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Could you download the [source code](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todosrc.tar.gz) and try to get it up and running on your computer? Oh and I already completed the official Poll app tutorial :-).

Comment: The asterisk was missing from my answer. I tested it and it's right.

Comment: Okay so I changed both `from dbe.todo.models import *` to `from todo.models import *` in both `mysite/todo/admin.py` and `mysite/todo/view.py`. Then I moved the templates to `mysite/templates` and updated the `mysite/settings.py` appropriately. But I am **still** getting an error about `dbe`. The error reads: `TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/

Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import dbe.todo.views. Error was: No module named dbe.todo.views`. `Exception Location:  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 167`

Comment: Remove "dbe." from everywhere.

Comment: Ok, finally. I did `grep -r "dbe" mysite` and removed every instance of `dbe` and it works now! Thanks a lot!